# PHP concatenation issue

Tags: php, xampp

I have a very simple code to prepare HTML tags based on the input array and type:

```
protected function tagPrep(array &$inpArr, string $type = NULL) {
    $tag  = NULL;
    $res  = NULL;
    $var1 = "<input ";
    $var2 = ">";
    try {
        $this->validateInput($inpArr, $type);
        $tag = (string) $this->prepHTML($inpArr);
        //$res = (self::INP_START . $tag . self::INP_END);
        //$res = ($var1 . $tag . $var2);
        //res = sprintf("<input %s >", $tag);
        $res = str_replace("%html%", $tag, "<input %html%>");
        if ($tag != NULL && strlen($tag))
            $this->setScript($res, GENCOPY_HTML);
        return $this;
        //
    }
    catch (Exception $ex) {
    }
}
```

validateInput() validates the tag inputs (in array) based on the type.
prepHTML() prepares the tag (as string) excluding the type (input, button, etc.).

prepHTML() returns the required string however all subsequent concatenation code fails. Variable $res is always blank

As PHP server I am using XAMPP Version: 7.0.9. Similar code is working in other files.

Comment: Its cause you are overwriting the $res var each time. Try using `.=`

Comment: its not supposed to retain the value, it pushes the value on to a stack [$this->setScript($res, GENCOPY_HTML)]. I have tried different ways of doing things, only one of them is required

Comment: What do you want to concatenate then?  There is no concatenation in your code at all, so it's hard to find the concatenation problem.

Comment: are you missing a foreach loop?

Comment: Thanks. I have tried concatinating. please check the first 2 commented line ($res = (self::INP_START . $tag . self::INP_END) AND $res = ($var1 . $tag . $var2)), I have tried using sprintf, i have tried using str_replace. all of them fails

Comment: No coderodour, not required. please review the commented code and the last str_replace, all of them fails

Comment: If you var_dump $tag before the concat, what is the value?

Comment: @James, $tag contains: string(164) "class = "jInput" type = "text" id = "UUID" name = "UUID" value = "YjU2OWM2ZjgtZWQ1Mi0zYmU4LTcyMGMtNDM4Y2JmMDliN2U4LTQ1WGFpTVhFLzlhYU0%3D" form = "174245829" hidden ". I just want to append '<input ' before the above string and '>' after the string.

Comment: You've got a try/catch block but nothing in the exception box, what happens if you echo $ex->getMessage()? Is an exception triggering somewhere you just aren't aware of?

Comment: @James, I have removed the code from the exception block to reduce the code. No exceptions raised as I have a debug statement in there (not printed)

Comment: Now, this is going to seem a really silly question, but when you think it's blank, have you view-sourced the response, to make sure it isn't ACTUALLY echo'ing it out, but as a hidden input you can't see on the page?

Comment: @James: I am checking the O/P in the browser using developer tools (Chrome), its not printing any hidden controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View Source on the output. You're echoing out a hidden field, I'm guessing the hidden field HTML is being echoed out, and as it's HTML of a hidden field, it's, well, hidden.

Comment: I am checking the O/P in the browser using developer tools (Chrome), its not printing any hidden controls

Comment: So when you view source (specifically view source) on the var_dump on res, it says string(172) ""?

Comment: And I ask because 172 characters is the exact length of the HTML for your hidden input.

Comment: You are absolutely rite. Its dumping but in a different section. it is working, thanks a lot for all the help to all the kind folks out there, appreciate it...

Answer (score -1):

use `\"` instead of `"` in your prepHTML method.

right now the value of `$tag` isn't a valid string, causing str_replace to crash.

trying it with PhpFiddle I get the following error message:

```
syntax error, unexpected 'jInput' (T_STRING)
```

Comment: any particular reason for the downvote? (as you can see my rep is low, I'd like some feedback to help improve my answers in the future)

Comment: Thanks Will. I tried the following: $res = ('<input ' . 'class = "jInput" type = "text" id = "UUID" name = "UUID" value = "YzljZDU4NDgtYTE2Zi0zNGZiLTc4ZGEtZDVkZWFjZTIyNGM1LTM4bzBKMGpLY3FYdlk%3D" form = "173838740" hidden ' . '>'); and still $res is BLANK

Comment: I have just hardcoaded the string to test and find the problem. That is just for testing/debugging purpose

Comment: where are you outputting? to a console or in a browser? If you are echo'ing in the browser then @James Hunt found your problem: it's being rendered as a hidden field

Comment: @jin I was addressing the downvoter, whoever he/she may be ;)

Comment: I am dumping $res in the browser using var_dump($res). Output is: string(172) "". No text but size is 172